# import mqttws31 into a javascript workerscript

Tags: javascript, qt, mqtt

I'm using Qt creator to build an embedded application. I've have an issue when I try to include the library `mqttws31.js` into a workerscript. I add it using `Qt.include()` and it seems to work, but when I try to create a Client object, it gives me the error: `ReferenceError: Paho is not defined`. I have to use a workerscript because I need the process to be non-blocking.

The code of the workerscript where I include the library and try to create the client is below:

```
Qt.include('mqttws31.js');

WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message){
    //create a new client
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname, port,'/mqtt', "clientId");

    //do some stuff
}
```

I tried to put the `Qt.include` inside the `onMessage` function, but without success.